# How does the C compiler handles different main function definitions?

Tags: c, linux, name-mangling

The main question is: How does the C compiler handles multiple definitions for the function main in different source codes?
 Like:

void main(void)

int main(void)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
...

I don't know if this has something to do with name mangling, that only occurs when a C code is linked against C++ code without using the extern "C" but also I was just querying through Linux programmer's manual (just plain man command on the shell) for the function open(man 2 open) and it shows two signatures for it:

OPEN(2)      Linux Programmer's Manual

NAME

```
   open, creat - open and possibly create a file or device
```

SYNOPSIS

```
   #include <sys/types.h>
   #include <sys/stat.h>
   #include <fcntl.h>

   int open(const char *pathname, int flags);
   int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);

   int creat(const char *pathname, mode_t mode);
```

how can this work ? It is handled like the definitions of the main function ?

Comment: I wonder if you mean multiple declarations of main with different types, or multiple definitions. It would help if you gave example code (a programme of your own) whose behaviour is not clear to you. It is also unclear what the question has to do with [linux] and [c++].

Comment: Name mangling does not happen to C names, but to overloaded C++ names, to accommodate the limitations of linkers. As such, it has no bearing on what a C compiler (and perhaps a linker) does with your programme.

Comment: This is no valid C code. C and C++ are **different** languages! Even identical syntax/grammar can have different semantics.

Comment: So I got that was kinda of dubious, sorry, I hope the last edit fixed that

Comment: @PJTraill I've tagged linux because the part about the open function mentioned where I've saw the manual of the open function, that  i think is posix only.

Comment: @joaopauloribeiro: As the title clearly states, it is Linux-specific. See section 3 for the POSIX version which does not list different signatures, but a variadic function.

Answer (score 4):

`open` doesn't actually have overloads or multiple declarations. It's declared as `open(const char *pathname, int flags, ...)` and the third argument is read with `va_arg` and interpreted as a `mode_t` when `flags` includes `O_CREAT`.

If you have multiple definitions of `main`, or multiple symbols that have any same C name for that matter, you will probably get a linker error.

Comment: I think I've misunderstood, the question about main it's not about having two or more definitions in the same source code, but how does the compiler handles different definitions in different codes, like I can do just void main(void) or int main(void)...

Comment: @joaopauloribeiro, the compiler is responsible for making sure that `main` gets called correctly by the C runtime. The way it is called has to take into account that it may or may not have arguments and may or may not return a value (on platforms where `main` is allowed to return `void` as an extension to the C standard). It can be treated as a special case; you won't necessarily get that kind of lenience with other functions.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I don't mean to say that the developer can write whatever and the compiler will figure it out. I agree with what you've said.

Comment: @zneak: No, it is the responsibility of the run-time/environment to call `main` properly. It is the responsibility of the compiler & linker to provide **exactly one** main` with the correct signature (i.e. parameter list and result).

Answer (score 3):

Typical implementations of the C programming language are tolerant against the caller passing too many arguments to a function. On UNIX-like systems, when the startup code calls into `main`, it passes three arguments as if `main` was declared as

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *environ[]);
```

where the third argument is the environment. If `main` was defined with less parameters than that, everything still works out just fine as with typical calling conventions, extra arguments are placed in such a way that they don't hurt (e.g. on the stack above the first arguments or in extra registers).

Historically, the `open` function worked similarly: `open` was declared without a prototype so the compiler could not check how many arguments you passed. The definition of `open` expected three arguments, if you only passed two, `open` would grab whatever is on the stack for the third argument which didn't matter as the third argument didn't influence the result when `open` was invoked without `O_CREAT`.

Comment: So if the open function grabs "whatever" is in the stack it could break the stack for other functions ?

Comment: As with everything in life - you can grab less than your share, but try taking more and suffer the consequences.

Comment: @joaopauloribeiro Since it never overwrites its arguments and since `open` is never the top stack frame, this is not a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Literally anyway it likes. If you don't declare `main` in one of the two manners proscribed by the standard, or you declare it in *both* manners, the compiler could teleport your car to the moon if it wanted. Any further rationalisation is pointless.

> `[C99: 5.1.2.2.1/1]:` *[..]* It shall be defined with a return type of `int` and with no parameters: *[..]* **or** with two parameters *[..]*
>
> `[C99: 5.1.2.2.1/2]:` If they are declared, the parameters to the main function shall obey the following constraints: *[..]*
>
> `[C99: 3.4.3/1]:` **undefined behavior**
> behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data, for which this International Standard imposes no requirements